# Sorting out irregular quarters (starting in July) using Tidyverse and Lubridate

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I am currently trying to generate (mutate) two columns:

- "NewThisYear" for observations that occurred in the current financial year
- "NewThisQuarter" for observations that occurred this current quarter

My usual approach involves the code attached. This code has worked for when the financial year starts in January but I can't figure out what would be a good approach to extract the following year (i.e 2022) for the first two quarters of the year that start in 2021. Would the best way to tackle this be to add + 1 to the year if the Quarter is 1|2 or is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Thanks for the pointers!

Code:

```
Calendar <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18780, 18787, 18794, 18801, 
                                              18808, 18815, 18822, 18829, 18836, 18843, 18850, 18857, 18864, 
                                              18871, 18878, 18885, 18892, 18899, 18906, 18913, 18920, 18927, 
                                              18934, 18941, 18948, 18955, 18962, 18969, 18976, 18983, 18990, 
                                              18997, 19004, 19011, 19018, 19025, 19032), class = "Date"), NameMonthShort = structure(c(6L, 
                                                                                                                                       6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
                                                                                                                                       9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
                                                                                                                                       12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", 
                                                                                                                                                                                "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
                                                                                                                                       ), class = c("ordered", "factor")), Year = c(2021, 2021, 2021, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    2022), Quarter = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), QuarterYear = c("4-2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "4-2021", "4-2021", "4-2021", "4-2021", "1-2021", "1-2021", "1-2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "1-2021", "1-2021", "1-2021", "1-2021", "1-2021", "1-2021", "1-2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "1-2021", "1-2021", "1-2021", "2-2021", "2-2021", "2-2021", "2-2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "2-2021", "2-2021", "2-2021", "2-2021", "2-2021", "2-2021", "2-2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "2-2021", "2-2021", "3-2022", "3-2022", "3-2022", "3-2022", "3-2022", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "3-2022")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            -37L))
Calendar <- Calendar %>%
  mutate(
    NewThisYear = case_when(
      Year == year(Sys.Date()) ~ "Yes",
      TRUE ~ as.character("No")
    ),
    NewThisQuarter = case_when(
      Year == year(Sys.Date()) & Quarter == quarter(Sys.Date(), with_year = F, fiscal_start = 7) ~ "Yes",
      TRUE ~ as.character("No")
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a little simpler to create some convenience functions:

```
library(lubridate); library(dplyr)

FY <- function(x) { year(x %m+% months(6)) }  # EDIT from %m-%
Qtr = function(x) { floor_date(x, "quarter") }

Calendar %>%
  mutate(qtr = Qtr(Date), FY = FY(Date),
         NewThisYear = FY(Date) == FY(Sys.Date()),
         NewThisQuarter = Qtr(Date) == Qtr(Sys.Date()))
```

Comment: Thanks Jon! I need to wrap my head around the answer a bit but have an initial question. I noticed that the value of NewThisYear comes out as TRUE but the value of FY stays as 2021 when the year should be 2022, can it be pushed to the next year once the financial year hits 1? If for some reason I wanted to start the financial year in April, would I just change the months value to (3)? Not really familiar with %m-%

Comment: Did a quick search on %m-% and saw that it substracts a value to the date. Went ahead and tried adding a plus sign and it did add a 1 year to the NewThisYear value but also assigned 2022 to the 4th Qtr 4 of 2021 :/

Comment: Ah yes, %m+%` makes more sense if the label for the FY is the latter year, which seems to be the typical case. Edited.

Comment: I added the + sign previously and it worked but I don't quite understand if I want to start the FY in lets say October why would it not work if I put 10 in the months? I tried all the numbers and it seemed to work if I put 3 instead. Is that not where the count starts for the year?

Comment: If the fiscal year starts in october, month 10 of the "prior" year, and you want any days in that month (or in nov or dec) to be labeled with the next calendar year, you'd need to add three months to them to put them into that year. You need to add as many months as your fiscal year puts into the prior calendar year. Oct -> 3; July -> 6; April -> 9.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for breaking it down like that, I get it now. Have a good one!